# How to modify another column of target in SQLAlchemy listens_for?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to generate the slug of an article everytime I modify the title, however, the slug remains the same even tho it's generated correctly (I printed it and it gave the expected output):

```
@event.listens_for(Articles.title, 'set')
def set_slug_on_title_change(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.slug = generate_slug(target.id, value)
```

The slug doesn't change.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.